# What's different between open App.app file and App.app/contents/MacOS/Electron on MacOS?

Tags: macos, electron

I have an electron application.It is an updater with download another application and toolchain.I can't open it with open Updater.app.However, I can use Updater.app/contents/MacOS/Electron to open it.

Here is the log:

```
Non-fatal error enumerating at <private>, continuing: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "未能打开文件“PlugIns”，因为它不存在。"
UserInfo={
 NSURL=PlugIns/ -- file:///private/var/folders/xn/08sc_nts0n11yyw_3ddlngdh0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A0F3B185-B4AB-4CC8-A3C5-86DAA22043D5/d/Updater.app/Contents/,
NSFilePath=/private/var/folders/xn/08sc_nts0n11yyw_3ddlngdh0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A0F3B185-B4AB-4CC8-A3C5-86DAA22043D5/d/Updater.app/Contents/PlugIns, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd1d2d13fe0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}
}
```

I would like to know the difference between Updater.app and Updater.app/contents/MacOS/Electron.

Comment: You appear to be affected by [App Translocation (a.k.a. Gatekeeper Path Randomization)](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/app-translocation.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updater.app is a macOS App Bundle. App Bundles are Apple's way of packaging a program - each one is basically just a folder containing an executable program and all the configuration files, helper executables, images, shipped libraries, and other resources the program needs to run.

In your case, `Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron` is probably the main executable of the app - `<App>/Contents/MacOS/` is usually the location of an App Bundle's main executable.

For further reading, look over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119262/3776548) which further explains the general concept of a macOS App Bundle.